# How do I change the color property of a class from another class?

Tags: vb.net, class, reference

This is a bit difficult to explain but basically:

I want to change the **Color** property of a class from another class: In this case, an animation class

> Form1 -> Contains object "ShapeClass" -> Contains "FillColor" and
>   "Position" property
>
> AnimatorClass -> Contains variable "SubjectProperty" which is the
>   object whose value is being changed throughout the animation. The sub
>   "run()" would change the value in the "ShapeClass" object

So here's how the animation works:

```
Dim Shape1 as ShapeClass = new ShapeClass()
Dim anim as AnimatorClass = new AnimatorClass()
anim.SubjectProperty = Shape1.Position
anim.run()
```

And the animation would run successfully: actually changing the **Position** property of the Shape1 object.

However, whenever a *Drawing.Color* is used as the **SubjectObject**, the actual value in Shape1.FillColor doesn't get changed. In all other situations, the **SubjectProperty** variable seems to be a reference to the actual property in the ShapeClass, and changes to SubjectProperty, go to the property it references, but this doesn't not seem to happen with the *Drawing.Color* class.

Could someone tell me why this is the case, and how to fix it? Thanks.

(Appologies if I explained it badly)

Comment: The issue you're seeing is likely the difference between a reference type and a value type. What is the type of `Position`? Also, show us the code that actually modifies the contents of `SubjectProperty`.

Comment: "this doesn't not seem to happen with the Drawing.Color class". That's because `Drawing.Color` is not a class.  It's a structure, i.e. a value type.  Assigning a value type from one place to another creates a copy, while assigning a reference type creates another reference to the same object.  Once you provide a bit more information so we're sure of what's going on, we can probably provide a solution.  One that comes to mind is using Refelection and passing in a `PropertyInfo` object on which you can call `SetValue`. LINQ may be able to help too.

Comment: I can't really show code since my actual code is like 300 lines, and basically impossible to narrow down. I probably should have included that `Position` is a class, that stores an x and y position. The specifics aren't really important other than the fact that its a class to describe a the position of the shape. When calling run(), the code basically does this: `SubjectProperty = Value`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : Thanks for pointing out that Drawing.Color is a structure, i didn't really know that. I'll take a look at Reflection and Linq, though I have a quick question: will Reflections in vb.net be similar to pointer variables in C++?

Comment: No, Reflection would not be like pointers.  Basically, you would have to create a `PropertyInfo` for the property you wanted to set and then pass that in along with the object you wanted to set it on.  You would then call the `SetValue` method of the property info and pass the object to set the property on and the value to set it to.

Comment: Ditch your position class and replace it with a POINT structure (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) and for the FillColor use a COLOR structure (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) In the Anim object change the SubjectObject to an OBJECT structure and then try it again. Posting your code would help you nail it far quicker... Members have posted several hundred lines of code so 300 lines is no problem...